# Symfony2 - Deployment cache no setfacl

Tags: debugging, caching, deployment, symfony

I'm trying to deploy my first Symfony2 app.

Blank screen when trying to access it.

Checking the log:

```
$ sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

> [...] Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Failed to write cache file [...]

Trying to put the good rights on cache & logs

```
$ sudo chmod +a "www-data allow delete,write,[...]" app/cache app/logs
```

> chmod: invalid mode: `+a'

Trying with setfacl

```
$ sudo setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx app/cache app/logs
```

> setfacl: app/cache: Operation not supported
>   setfacl: app/logs: Operation not supported

I imagine my partition is not mounted with acl or something similar.

Couldn't I simply chown www-data cache & logs ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To use *setfacl*, you first need to install acl utilities:

```
# Provided Apt can be used for package management
$ sudo apt-get install acl
```

Then remount the disk partition containing your symfony2 project:

```
# Remount the partition containing your Symfony2 application
# e.g. we could remount the root (/) partition   
$ sudo mount -o remount,acl / # 

# we could also remount the /var partition in our app lives in /var/www  
$ sudo mount -o remount,acl /var  #
```

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs

Comment: thanks for you answer, but could explain better what do you mean with "when this partition is /"?, could you give any example in what case the argument "/" should be different?

Comment: [This doc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs) (for Ubuntu) helped me to understand how to use ACLs

Answer (score 6):

Since you're not supposed to develop on the deployment server, just give the whole app to the `www-data` user:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/the/root/of/your/app
```

Comment: That's what I did finally. Thanks

Comment: But some functions seems needing to write on cache and log, like `php app/console doctrine:schema:create` ...

Comment: You could also potentially uncomment/add umask(0) in app_dev.php, app.php and console. The developers of Symfony dont recommend it but if you dont have access to facl and cant get the permissions running correctly this will do the trick.